# Stored Procedure Transaction

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, commit, rollback

I have never used a Transaction, Commit and Rollback before and now I need to use one.  I have checked around online, etc for examples to make sure that I am in fact using this correctly but I am still not sure if I have coded this correct.  I am hoping someone can review and advise me if this seems correct.

Basically I have 2 databases for an application. One is an archive - meaning data that is no longer going to be manipulated by the users will be moved to this DB.  But in the event they ever need it, I will move the needed data back to the main database for use.  My stored proc is below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spReopenClosed] 
(
    @Return_Message VARCHAR(1024) = ''  OUT,        
    @IID        uniqueidentifier,
    @OpenDate   smalldatetime,
    @ReopenedBy uniqueidentifier
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

/******************************
*  Variable Declarations
*******************************/
    DECLARE     @ErrorCode  int  



/******************************
*  Initialize Variables
*******************************/

    SELECT @ErrorCode = @@ERROR

    IF @ErrorCode = 0

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        /****************************************************************************
        * Step 1
        * Copy the Closed from the Archive
        ****************************************************************************/
        INSERT INTO OPS.dbo.SM_T_In
        SELECT          
        FROM OPS_ARCHIVE.Archive.SM_T_In    W
        WHERE W.GUID = @IID
            AND W.OpenDate = @OpenDate


        IF @ErrorCode <> 0
            BEGIN
                -- Rollback the Transaction
                ROLLBACK

                RAISERROR ('Error in Copying from the archive', 16, 1)
                RETURN
            END


        /****************************************************************************
        * Step 2
        * copy the notes
        ****************************************************************************/
        INSERT INTO OPS.dbo.SM_T_Notes
        SELECT 
        FROM OPS_ARCHIVE.Archive.SM_T_Notes W
        WHERE W.GUID = @IID

        IF @ErrorCode <> 0
            BEGIN
                -- Rollback the Transaction
                ROLLBACK

                RAISERROR ('Error in copying the notes', 16, 1)
                RETURN
            END

        /****************************************************************************
        * Step 3
        * Delete the from the Archive - this will also delete the notes
        ****************************************************************************/
        DELETE
        FROM OPS_ARCHIVE.Archive.SM_T_In
        WHERE OPS_ARCHIVE.Archive.SM_T_In.GUID = @IID

        IF @ErrorCode <> 0
            BEGIN
                -- Rollback the Transaction
                ROLLBACK

                RAISERROR ('Error in deleting the items from the Archive', 16, 1)
                RETURN
            END

        COMMIT

        BEGIN
            SELECT  @ErrorCode  = @@ERROR

            IF @ErrorCode = 0
                    SELECT  @Return_Message = 'All data was moved over'
        END



/*************************************
*  Get the Error Message for @@Error
*************************************/
    IF @ErrorCode <> 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @Return_Message = [Description]     -- Return the SQL Server error
          FROM  master.dbo.SYSMESSAGES
         WHERE  error = @ErrorCode
    END

/*************************************
*  Return from the Stored Procedure
*************************************/
    RETURN @ErrorCode                               -- =0 if success,  <>0 if failure
END
```

I have two inserts that move the data from 2 tables from the Archive database.  If those inserts are successful, then I will delete the data from the Archive DB.  I would appreciate any feedback on this, I need to make sure that I am doing this properly.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? It makes a big differnce in the method.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Oh well i rewrite quickly your SP using the concept **TRY CATCH and the TRANSACTION** as you requested but i didnt check it.

This code will work in **SQL 2005/2008**

Let me know if this feedback can be useful for you

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spReopenClosed] 
(
    @Return_Message VARCHAR(1024) = ''  OUT,        
    @IID        uniqueidentifier,
    @OpenDate   smalldatetime,
    @ReopenedBy uniqueidentifier
)
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

/******************************
*  Variable Declarations
*******************************/
    DECLARE     @ErrorCode  int  
    DECLARE     @ErrorStep  varchar(200)

/******************************
*  Initialize Variables
*******************************/

    SELECT @ErrorCode = @@ERROR

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRAN
        /****************************************************************************
        * Step 1
        * Copy the Closed from the Archive
        ****************************************************************************/

        SELECT @ErrorStep = 'Error in Copying from the archive';

        INSERT INTO OPS.dbo.SM_T_In
        SELECT *         
        FROM OPS_ARCHIVE.Archive.SM_T_In
        WHERE GUID = @IID
            AND W.OpenDate = @OpenDate


        /****************************************************************************
        * Step 2
        * copy the notes
        ****************************************************************************/

        SELECT @ErrorStep = 'Error in copying the notes'

        INSERT INTO OPS.dbo.SM_T_Notes
        SELECT *
        FROM OPS_ARCHIVE.Archive.SM_T_Notes
        WHERE GUID = @IID

        /****************************************************************************
        * Step 3
        * Delete the from the Archive - this will also delete the notes
        ****************************************************************************/

        SELECT @ErrorStep = 'Error in deleting the items from the Archive'

        DELETE
        FROM OPS_ARCHIVE.Archive.SM_T_In
        WHERE OPS_ARCHIVE.Archive.SM_T_In.GUID = @IID

    COMMIT TRAN

    SELECT  @ErrorCode  = 0, @Return_Message = 'All data was moved over'

    /*************************************
    *  Return from the Stored Procedure
    *************************************/
    RETURN @ErrorCode                               -- =0 if success,  <>0 if failure

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    /*************************************
    *  Get the Error Message for @@Error
    *************************************/
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK

    SELECT @ErrorCode = ERROR_NUMBER()
        , @Return_Message = @ErrorStep + ' '
        + cast(ERROR_NUMBER() as varchar(20)) + ' line: '
        + cast(ERROR_LINE() as varchar(20)) + ' ' 
        + ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' > ' 
        + ERROR_PROCEDURE()

    /*************************************
    *  Return from the Stored Procedure
    *************************************/
    RETURN @ErrorCode                               -- =0 if success,  <>0 if failure

END CATCH
```

Comment: Good example! Thanks

Comment: I tried forcing errors at different points using code similar to the above and works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First, databases are fairly reliable.  And if they fail, you have a bigger problem than handling individual transactions. So my feedback would be that you have too much error checking for a simple transaction.  A failing insert is such an unusual event that you normally wouldn't write code to handle it.

Second, this code won't actually "catch" errors:

```
IF @ErrorCode <> 0
```

An error in the SQL statement will abort the stored procedure and return to the client.  You'd have to [try ... catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) to actually handle an error in a stored procedure.

Third, I try to avoid `raiserr`.  It can do unexpected things both on the server and the client side.  Instead, consider using an `output` parameter to return error information to the client program.