# How do I correctly use Transaction Scope for simple ETL process?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This relates to SQL Server 2008.

I am writing a procedure that moves data from a production database to a periodic cache database for BI purposes.

Both databases are on the same SQL instance, hence I plan to avoid using SSIS at this stage.

I need to:

1. Remove all existing data from the cache.
2. Select all business branches into a table.
3. Select all sales divisions into a table
4. Select and transform the actual data.
5. If any of 2 - 4 fail, then I need to rollback and return a text error. So that the data in the cache remains as it was before the procedure was called.

I have looked at:
[Stored Procedure Transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252757/stored-procedure-transaction)

I thought the try, catch might be overkill.

What would be the best practice for this?
Is it as simple as using

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Do stuff

IF @@ERROR <> 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Edit - This post is very useful as well:
[How does SQL Server treat statements inside stored procedures with respect to transactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622069/how-does-sql-server-treat-statements-inside-stored-procedures-with-respect-to-tr?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following approach:

First, I'd use the TRY CATCH syntax within a stored procedure.

Instead of removing all existing data I would rename the tables (cache, business branches, and sales divisions) and create new ones with the same name and format.
I'm not sure how complicated step 4 is. But if it's rather straight forward I'd place it in a separate transaction within the TRY CATCH block to allow the rollback.

If any of the code block fails, it'll jump to the CATCH section. Within that section I'd rollback step 4 (if needed), drop the newly created tables and rename the old ones.

Edit: and if there wasn't any error, drop the renamed tables.

Answer (score 1):

As for the transactional part I'd go for a try catch solution to deal with the transaction scopes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY
    -- Generate a constraint violation error.
    DELETE FROM Production.Product
    WHERE ProductID = 980;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```